# Why is it that I always experience sleep paralysis (suffocating) very often?

Tags: sleep

Is there anything I can do to avoid sleep paralysis? Has this got anything  to do with astral projection?

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism.SE kare. This question may not be considered on topic for this site.

Comment: You should really see a doctor before trying to make a connection with Buddhism or any other spiritual path, of course Buddhism can help people, but maybe not the kind of help you are searching for right now.

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism.SE. I've put your question on hold since your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with Buddhism and so would fall outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: While I agree with the off-topic verdict and mostly konrod01's post that one should one first consult a doctor is very good advice, but I can't help but to think that the question could become "on topic" easily if the question would include: "Do buddhist texts say anything about this?" or "could this be helped with meditation or meditation induced?

Comment: That's a question for the [meta](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @kare If you're experiencing sleep paralysis and you're conscious, then you're half way to OBE. Then try to higher your vibrations (aka [electric feel](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/that-electric-feel-body-sensation-during-meditation)) and thing of moving up and viola (take a bit of practise). If you experiencing some kind of suffocating, maybe you're sleeping on [black stream](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7567/385).

Comment: Advanced meditation will fix this problem eventually but it is the equivalent of learning brain surgery to cure a headache.

Answer (score 2):

I once read that meditation, yoga etc. can help to get a deeper breath and to switch more to belly breathing instead of breast breathing. Thus, those practices may potentially support your condition. Nevertheless, I think you won't find the reason or cure for it in Buddhism.