# Vibrating Sensation in Middle of forehead during meditation?

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-effects

Recently during my meditation sessions I have been getting a vibrating sensation between the eyebrows sometimes it can be quite intense.

I have looked online and from what I can find it suggests this sensation refers to the "third eye". Just wondering if this is mentioned in any buddhists texts and is sensation normal?

Comment: I have pressure on my upper nose while doing vipassana meditation, why it is happening?

Comment: @dineshsj This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @dineshsj Welcome to Buddhism.SE! As ChrisW indicates: you have a question, you can ask it separately using the "Ask Question" button in the upper right hand corner.

Comment: See also: [“Electric Feel” body sensation during meditation](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/that-electric-feel-body-sensation-during-meditation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the sensation is a normal condition.

It is just muscle/nerve spasms. They may be happening throughout the day but go largely unnoticed. They are also at level of neuron firings so you typically will not be able to see them physically. During meditation you are probably more aware of the tiny changes in your body. One thing I notice during meditation is how loud my stomach has been this last week. The more you become aware of them the more intense they will probably appear to manifest. Unless it is a medical condition such as a hemifacial spasm they will typically go away on their own.

Answer (score 6):

This is your 1st glimpse of arising and passing away. When you practice more you will see there is no solidity any where and your body is completely a mass of arraigning and passing sensations which manifests them self are vibrations. If you not be attached or averse to them as this creates negativity.

Answer (score 2):

Never think 3rd eye activation or Kundolini bla bla. If you think so, your ego is growing up with meditation.

Before everything, you kill ego first then try to become no mind state.

Then ----

Comment: This is not answering the OP questions.The Op is asking if the "third eye is mentioned in the Buddhist texts? and if the sensation is normal?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of meditation are you practicing right now? I believe you are practicing Anapana and have not yet ventured into Vipassana. When you will start doing Vipassana, you will realise that there are vibrations constantly happening all over the body. We use these vibrations, this arising and falling of sensations to ascertain the reality of impermanence and anatta. So basically your mindfulness has increased making you aware of these sensations. A word of caution will be not to get attached to these sensations...sometimes you may not feel them and sometimes these sensations may be painful...remaining equanimous all the time is the key.

Comment: Yes I am practicing anapana meditation for 12 months have noticed in my longer session (45 mins +) that this vibration sensation occurs. Usually I bring my attention back to the breath and it seems to disappear but just wanted to know if this was something others experience and it seems like it is normal.

Comment: yes its very normal...these sensations were happening even before just that now you have heightened your awareness

Answer (score 1):

This sensation is normal during meditation and the place is called [Ajna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajna) (or third-eye chakra - the mind's eye). In statues of buddhas it's placed on the forehead as a most previous jewel.

In Tibetan buddhism, this chakra is at the end of the central channel, which runs up the body to the top of the head, and then over and down, terminating at the forehead. The two side channels continue onwards towards the two nostrils and end there. [Source: [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajna#Comparisons_with_other_systems)

From a spiritual point of view, we could compare the third eye to the temple's portal to the sacred places or the bridge allowing mind communication.

The purpose of meditation is to reveal this natural subtle perception (vibrating sensation). The best results are achieved when you don't use your imagination/visualisation, so things will come to you naturally (just flow with what comes). So if you feel vibration (or pressure, density) between the eyebrows, don't pay attention to it, just focus on the vibration and try to connect this energy with your throat chakra ([Vishuddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishuddha)) in order to create the circulation of the life force ([Lung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lung_(Tibetan_Buddhism))/[Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi)/[Vijñāna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vij%C3%B1%C4%81na)), so you can sense your light/astral/etheric body.

See also:

- [“Electric Feel” body sensation during meditation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/that-electric-feel-body-sensation-during-meditation) at Buddhism SE
- (book) [Geshe Kelsang Gyatso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelsang_Gyatso). [Tantric Grounds and Paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/9780948006333)
- (book) Awakening the Third Eye by Samuel Segan ([PDF](http://www.eso-garden.com/specials/awakening_the_third_eye.pdf))