# Electric blood, electric breathe, electric ball and one beam

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-breath

I have done meditation for 6 week now. My pulse has now become so electric even not when I am meditating, before i was Activated my pulse used to pulsating back and forward but now its more alive. When i make a triangle/pyramid with my hands, i can make one electric ball inside and if really focus it will become a beam of electricity that feels like Oneness. When i breathe i feel a cold layer of electricity on my skin, the breathing is controlling my electricity.
My feelings are growing everyday i feel like i am getting strong for each day 
I have very little experience with this so if anybody know anything please talk to me.

Comment: What type of meditation are you practicing?

Comment: When i close my eyes i get these visions how to do it and i just follow that, and calibrate my pulse. I have never done any research on the subject i have no clue what kind i am doing. One tip i use high frequency vibrational sounds thats called binuary beats its free on youtube.

Comment: Maybe you can find some answers in this [question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/that-electric-feel-body-sensation-during-meditation?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

You started meditating. If you're having strange experiences, you're doing it right. The "truth" is coming into view and your ego is dying. When your ego is loosing control, he will do everything to gain that control back. Thus, your ego is giving you pleasant experiences. Your ego wants you to crave for these experiences. He wants you to play with them until your death. If you play with the experiences, you'll never see what's behind your ego, thus you'll never gain control of it, never see the "truth" and no liberation from suffering will follow in this life.

If these experiences are interesting to you and you crave for more, then explore the experiences you described, don't fight them or search them, if they arise just play with them. Sooner or later you'll reach a point where there will be nothing new to explore in these experiences. Nothing new to play with. When you reach this point, start asking yourself "Why these experiences arise? What's behind these experiences? What's the cause?". Explore your mind and search for the cause. You'll find the "truth" and liberation from suffering will follow.

If you're willing to let go of these experiences now, then let go of them. If they arise, just relax, empty your mind, do nothing, and let them cease without trying or wanting anything. When you'll reach a point where you'll be able to just observe your mind, without reacting, without craving, clinging or aversion arising in your mind, these experiences will stop. Then, you'll be able to explore your mind further and you'll find the "truth" and liberation from suffering will follow.

Comment: okei sounds very reasonable thnx